# Add linebreak in Paypal summary

Tags: c#, newline, paypal

I am trying to add a `<br />` html tag in paypal `SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType.OrderDescription`

I am using C# and custom cart, here's my code

```
SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType test = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();       
test.OrderDescription = ShoppingCart().Replace("each", "<br />");
```

I've put all shopping cart items info in orderDescription and want to add a break line in between each of them.

I also tried `\r\n` and `System.Environment.NewLine`, none of them work.

Comment: How are you looking at it?  Are you trying to make it show up on Paypal's end?  Or on your own site?  Or are you looking at it in the debugger?

Comment: I am looking to show it on paypal summery wall. Currently, it showed something like this on paypal summery wall.

Comment: Descriptions
Basket of Flowers Quantity:1 Price: £160 <br /> Santa's sleigh and reindeer Quantity:1 Price: £132 <br />

Comment: I want it to show new line instead of <br /> on paypal summery wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want to do is not possible in the way you're trying to do it.  If you want multiple items to show up in the summary, you need to send multiple items to Paypal.  They don't provide any mechanism for putting linebreaks into a given field, and if they don't provide it it can't be done.

The order description field is for an overall summary of your order.  To include multiple products, you need to include multiple `PaymentDetailsItemType` objects in the `test.PaymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem` field.